# calling second applet once first applet is loaded in JSP/JSF/HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf, applet

I am working on a JSP/ JSF page where two applets are embeded using  tag.
Problem is the first applet is having some information that will be updated on the page and the second applet must use that info to load properly.

I cannot find a way where i can control calling of the applets. (These applets are third party applets other wise i could have combined both applets). i want to know how i can know the first applet is loaded and then call/enable or show 2nd applet.

below are the tags i used for applets on my page.

```
<object
              name="CSHelper" id="CSHelperId"
              classid="clsid:9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-5F499D93" 
              width="100%" 
              HEIGHT="0" 
              ALIGN="middle" 
              codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0_11-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,5,0,11">

              <param name="code" value="ClientUtil"/>
              <param name="ARCHIVE" value="HelperApplet.jar"/>

            </object>


              <object style="display:none"
                  name="ivrTelephonyBarName" id="ivrTelephonyBarId"
                  classid="clsid:89C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-0599D93"
                  width="100%"
                  HEIGHT="75"
                  ALIGN="middle"
                  codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0_11-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,5,0,11">

                  <param name="code" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getAppletJarClass()%>"/>
                  <param name="ARCHIVE" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getAppletJar()%>"/>

                  <param id="AGENT_ID" name="AGENT_ID" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getAgentID()%>"/>
                  <%--<param id="sAgentID" name="sAgentID" value="0202"/>--%>
                  <param id="AGENT_PASS" name="AGENT_PASS" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getAgentPassword()%>"/>
                  <param id="INSTRUMENT" name="INSTRUMENT" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getInstrument()%>"/>

                  <param id="params" name="params" value="<%=cTIConnectionParams.getParams()%>"/>

                  <param id="iconsPath" name="iconsPath" value="<%=contextCtiUrl%>images/appletIcons/"/>
                  <param id="configPath" name="configPath" value="<%=contextCtiUrl%>"/>
              </object>
```

I want to laod "CSHelperId" first and then the last when which is not diaplyed purposely.
Any technique will work for me.

Comment: if (first applet loaded) then Call2ndApplet() otherwise Wait();

Answer (score 0):

you can do it mixing javascript code in your 1st applet

```
    public void init() {
       JSObject document = JSObject.getWindow(this);
       String evalString = "document.getElementById('secondAppletPanel').innerHTML = ";
       document.eval(evalString + secondAppletHtmlString);
    }
```

now you can build a string with parameters calculated by your first applet modifiyng the string content, also
you need to place and empty div with id secondAppletPanel where you want the second applet to appear and add the **mayscript** attribute to your first applet (more info [JSObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html)
)